# Subscribing to an event of a base class

Tags: c#

I am trying to subscribe to an event that is in my base class but the method in my derived class doesn't seem to trigger whenever that event is triggered. Sample code is below.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
        public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

        public event EventHandler Event;

        protected virtual void OnEvent(EventArgs ea)
        {
            if (this.Event!= null)
            {
                this.Event(null, ea);
            }
        }

}
```

```
public partial class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.Event+= DoSomething;
        }

        private void DoSomething(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Do Something here.
        }
}
```

BaseClass.OnEvent is called in another control that has the same base class and the derived class where I want to subscribe to is inside another control. Is this possible?

Comment: What is `EventHandlere`? Isn't that meant to be `EventArgs e`? Otherwise it doesn't match the delegate.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like WinForms or WebForms. Is that the case?

Comment: Why are you declaring your own delegate when the `EventHandler` delegate already exists?

Comment: Based on the code you have posted, that event is never raised, so there's nothing to handle. If you haven't actually posted all the relevant code, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You shouldn't really be handling an event of a base class anyway. If a base class has a member `SomeEvent` then it should also have a `protected virtual` method `OnSomeEvent` that raises that event. Derived classes should override that method rather than handling the event. You might read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) for more information.

Comment: [Works for me](https://rextester.com/HBS64673) - can you be more specific about the problems you're facing?

Comment: @Dai yes. This is webforms.

Comment: @Greg Why are you using WebForms in 2022?

Comment: I have updated the post. Basically, the BaseClass is being used as the base class for another ascx and in that control, base.OnEvent is being called. I expected that when that is triggered, my subscription to base.Event in my other ascx page to trigger based on the base.OnEvent call from the other ascx.

Comment: @Dai Because this is the framework that the system is using. I did not choose this.

Comment: 90% if the time in WebForms you don’t need to use `event`s. Just use overrides. Note that you **must** call `base.OnFoo` somewhere inside your `override OnFoo` to raise the event because WebForms (and WinForms) don’t allow subclasses to raise most events themselves directly. But anyway, just ditch using events - they’re probably the #1 reason for memory-leaks in .NET.

Comment: @Dai Thanks, unfortunately I can't see any other way. The other ascx is a compiled module from a third party developer. We need the functions from that control and then detect when the event has been triggered from that control so that we can add our own logic after the other ascx has executed its own logic.

Comment: I’m having trouble imagining a situation where that’s the case - but for the sake of discussion I’ll believe you. There is another alternative (and it’s my personal favourite, because _I bloody well absolutely **HATE** external compiled-DLL-only WebForms control libraries with a burning passion_) and that’s to use ILSpy or Reflector to convert that .dll back into a fully editable C# project and sources that you now control. Try it. It’s a very empowering feeling.

Comment: @Dai Have already done that but it would need to be tweaked since it wouldn't work with a direct copy and paste and unfortunately, I don't have the time to be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> BaseClass.OnEvent is called in another control that has the same base class and the derived class where I want to subscribe to is inside another control. Is this possible?

If you have a derived class and you have two instances of this derived class, the method of instance one won't be called if anything happens in instance two.

In your case you even have two different derived classes, sharing one base class and at runtime you have at least one instance of each derived class, which means, there is no *communication* between these two.

If you need to *link* two instances together you have to do something like this:

```
var instanceOne = new DerivedClassOne();
var instanceTwo = new DerivedClassTwo();

// When something in one happens, let two know:
instanceOne.OnEvent += (sender, e) => instanceTwo.ReactOnOtherChange();
```